# Memory leak in adding list values

Tags: python, list, memory-leaks

i'm new to python and have big memory issue. my script runs 24/7 and each day it allocates about 1gb more of my memory. i could narrow it down to this function:

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8
import gc
from pympler import muppy
from pympler import summary
from pympler import tracker


v_list = [{ 
     'url_base' : 'http://www.immoscout24.de',
     'url_before_page' : '/Suche/S-T/P-',
     'url_after_page' : '/Wohnung-Kauf/Hamburg/Hamburg/-/-/50,00-/EURO--500000,00?pagerReporting=true',}]

# returns url
def get_url(v, page_num):
    return v['url_base'] + v['url_before_page'] + str(page_num) + v['url_after_page']


while True:
    gc.enable()

    for v_idx,v in enumerate(v_list):

        # mem test ouput
        all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
        sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
        summary.print_(sum1)


        # magic happens here
        url = get_url(v, 1)


        # mem test ouput
        all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
        sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)
        summary.print_(sum1)

        # collects unlinked objects
        gc.collect()
```

**Output:**

```
======================== | =========== | ============
                    list |       26154 |     10.90 MB
                     str |       31202 |      1.90 MB
                    dict |         507 |    785.88 KB
```

expecially the list attribute is getting bigger and bigger each cycle around 600kb and i don't have an idea why. in my opinion i do not store anything here and the url variable should be overwritten each time. so basically there should be any memory consumption at all.

what am i missing here? :-)

Comment: When you run just this example code—in particular, with this minimal `get_url` function—you see 600KB of list storage every loop? Or you see that with your real program, which does "magic" that you're not showing us?

Comment: Yes, if I run this example code I get around 600KB of list storage every loop. Python 2.7.2 on macos and linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "memory leak" is 100% caused by your testing for memory leaks. The `all_objects` list ends up maintaining a list of almost every object you ever created—even the ones you don't need anymore, which would have been cleaned up if they weren't in `all_objects`, but they are.

As a quick test:

- If I run this code as-is, I get the `list` value growing by about 600KB/cycle, just as you say in your question, at least up to 20MB, where I killed it.
- If I add `del all_objects` right after the `sum1 =` line, however, I get the `list` value bouncing back and forth between 100KB and 650KB.

If you think about why this is happening, it's pretty obvious in retrospect. At the point when you call `muppy.get_objects()` (except the first time), the previous value of `all_objects` is still alive. So, it's one of the objects that gets returned. That means that, even when you assign the return value to `all_objects`, you're not freeing the old value, you're just dropping its refcount from 2 to 1. Which keeps alive not just the old value itself, but every element within it—which, by definition, is everything that was alive last time through the loop.

If you can find a memory-exploring library that gives you weakrefs instead of normal references, that might help. Otherwise, make sure to do a `del all_objects` at some point before calling `muppy.get_objects` again. (Right after the only place you use it, the `sum1 =` line, seems like the most obvious place.)

Comment: oh dear... the funny thing is, in my real program somewhere is a leak, because it runs without the muppy stuff. i obviously have to search again. this time with 'del all_objects'. thank you mate!

Comment: Or simply don't store it in a variable: `summary.print_(summary.summarize(muppy.get_objects()))`

Comment: @Ngenator: Yeah, I was thinking about recommending that. What it comes down to is, which is clearer to someone (like the OP in 6 months) who needs to read or extend this code? I think the explicit `del` serves as a nice reminder that we've just created a list of the entire universe… but on the other hand you could argue that reminder isn't important enough to let it get in the way of the code.